# SignTool.exe Missing Visual Basic 2008

Tags: vb.net, signtool

When I try to publish a project, the error shows:

```
Error 2. SignTool.exe Missing.
```

I searched on my computer for SignTool.exe, the file doesn't exist.
I installed the Windows SDK, that didnt work, the file still doesn't exist. Then I installed the .Net framework, Silverlight, then reinstalled the whole Microsoft Visual Basic. 
The file still doesn't exist.

Where can i download SignTool.exe?

Answer (score 0):

**signtool.exe** is part of the .NET SDK. You'll need to download that, which will install it into the proper location.

You should be able to find the .NET SDK with a search on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com). There's no point in posting a link here, because they change over time or as new versions are released. (You can also find it by searching Google for "dot net sdk", which returns many different links to the Microsoft pages.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but installing the Windows SDK did not work for me (signtool.exe was still missing from my machine).

I stumbled across this solution: http://www.benedykt.net/2015/08/12/missing-signtool-exe-w-visual-studio-2015/

Basically:

- Open Programs and Features
- Select 'Microsoft Visual Studio [version]' and click Change
- And select 'ClickOnce Publishing Tools' for installation